# Particle systems doesn't appear in builded project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particles

In my scene, I have a few simple particles systems. When I run the game in the editor, everything works fine. But when I build the project, particles don't appear on the screen. When I try to swap them on meshes and build works fine. I use only Unity standard shaders and added it in Quality settings.

Comment: What platform are you building for?  If you try another platform does it work?

Comment: @slaphshot33324, hi. I build for PC (Windows 10)